# Prove that $\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

> Prove that $\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$

I've already proved that $\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is both not open and closed in $\mathbb R$ by using the points $0$ and $1$. In doing this, I've used the Euclidean distance as the metric. Is it right to do so, or should this be proved using an arbitrary metric ? (please comment on this - the exercise mentions nothing about the metric on $\mathbb R$)

I know I can prove $A=\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed by proving that for every convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \in A$.

On the other hand how can $A$ be closed ? Let $b$ be an irrational number in $[0,1]$. How can we find $r > 0$ such that $B_r(b) \subseteq A^C$ ?

Comment: Are you sure that your set without $0$ is open or closed?

Comment: sorry, it should be "both not open and closed".

Comment: As for your question regarding choice of metric, the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ is the one generated by the Euclidian "absolute difference" metric. There are a number of other metrics giving the same topology, and any one of them would suffice. Any topological property you can prove using the usual metric (compactness, continuity, open- / closedness etc.) can be demonstrated, with the same result, using any of the other metrics.

Comment: Would you mention the name of some of the other metrics, then I will look them up. But could I find a metric such that the proof fails ?

Comment: $d_1(x, y) = 2|x - y|$, $d_2(x, y) = \max(1, |x - y|)$, $d_3(x, y) = \sqrt{|x - y|}$ are three examples off the top of my head. On the real number line there aren't many named metrics, but once you get to higher dimensions there are a few, the most interesting ones aquired by changing the power $n$ (this example would be in $\Bbb R^2$):
$$
d_n((x_1, x_2), (y_1,y_2))=\sqrt[n]{|x_1-y_1|^n+|x_2 - y_2|^n}
$$
where $n = 2$ is the usual Euclidian distance. That said, in _any_ metric on _any_ space a singleton is always a closed set. So would the set of a converging sequence union its limit, I think.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. So proving something in topology like this, it is assumed when dealing with $\mathbb R^k$, we always use $d_{Eu}$, if nothing is mentioned about the metric ? And in a theorem proving something about $\mathbb R^k$, if nothing is said about metric, we assume $d_{Eu}$ ? Why is it not more explicit what metric we are using in exercises and theorems ? The way Things are laid out makes me think that statements holds for every metric.

Comment: @user111854 That's because when we say $\Bbb R^k$, we really mean $(\Bbb R^k, \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the standard topology (yes, this is would be almost universally assumed unless explicitly stated otherwise). The thing is, this topology is the same whether we use the Euclidian metric on $\Bbb R^k$, or if we use the absolute difference metric on $\Bbb R$ and build $\Bbb R^k$ as a direct prouct of $k$ copies of $\Bbb R$. This is very handy, and ensures that it makes sense to talk about _the_ standard topology, and not the two standard topologies.

Comment: See also [Is $\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \left\{ 0\right\}$ closed set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545357) and [Prove that $ S=\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\frac{1}{n}\}\right)$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/394570)

Answer (score 7):

More elementary:

Let $x \in \mathbf{R}\setminus A$. If $x < 0$ or $x > 1$, finding a ball centered at $x$ and contained in $\mathbf{R}\setminus A$ is trivial. If $0 < x < 1$, then $1/(n+1) < x < 1/n$ for some $n$, this gives you an open interval of $\mathbf{R}\setminus A$ of non-zero length which contains $x$, in which you can fit a ball centered at $x$.

Comment: Thanks, fkraiem - I really like your answer, which use very basic ideas and does not involve the use of more advanced theorems.

Comment: @fkraiem Can you be more explicit please? How can this be proved in topology?

Answer (score 3):

Hints assuming the usual topology on $\;\Bbb R\;$:

1)  A subset of the reals is closed iff it contains all its limit points;

2) If a real sequence converges then any subsequence also converges and to the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

Twisted proof: prove directly that the set is compact. Given a open cover, the open set containing 0 will contain almost all the elements of the set.

Answer (score 2):

Notations:

1. $A^C$ means the complement of $A$, i.e. $A \cup A^C = U$. In
   general, $U = \mathbb{R}$ unless there is a specific explanation.
2. $(s_n)$ means a sequence. For example, $(\frac{1}{n})$ means the
       sequence $(1, 1/2,1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6,...)$, i.e. $s_n = \frac{1}{n}$
       where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Proof:

Let $A = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$. For proving $A$ is a closed set, it equals to prove $A^C$ is an open set. Observing that the sequence $s_n = \frac{1}{n}$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) forming a strictly decreasing sequence, hence, we could construct a bunches of sets such that for set $S_n$: $\sup{S_n}=s_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\inf S_n = s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$, $\sup S_n \notin S_n$ and $\inf S_n \notin S_n$, then no element from the sequence $s_n$ would be in the sets $S_n$.

Therefore, $A^C = \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} (s_{n+1},s_n) \cup (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$.

Because the union of ***any*** collection of open sets is an open set, clearly, each $S_n$ is an open set and $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$ are open sets. Therefore $A^C$ is open [1] (Contrastively, the *intersection* of ***finitely*** many open sets is an open set). Since $A = \mathbb{R} - A^C$ and $A^C$ is an open set, we proved that $A$ is a closed set by the definition of closed set.

Reference:

[1] Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus, 2nd Edition. Kenneth A. Ross. Page 87, discussion 13.7, Springer, 2013.