# $A=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}=\{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is closed or open.?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

my friend say that $A$ is closed.

$$A=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}=\{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I cant prove it..

Although I think it is not closed.

if it set is closed,, how prove it?

Comment: "my friend say that $A$ is closed"

Comment: $A$ is neither closed nor open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with usual metric).

Comment: What is the space we are taking the closure in? This question is incomplete as stated.

Comment: Closure depends on some ambient space. The set $A$ is closed in the space $A$, but not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric.

Comment: Why do you ask is if it is "open or closed"?  What if it is neither?  Or both?

Comment: But if you add $0$, you get a closed set. See: [Prove that $\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665896) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/665896). (You can also have a look at some of the posts linked as related questions in the sidebar on the right.)

Answer (score 6):

$0$ is a limit point of $A$ by [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle) but $0 \notin A$, so $A$ isn't closed.

Comment: thanks, other form that prove 0 is limit point of $A$??

Comment: What does the Archimedean principle have to do with this?

Comment: @goblin you would need it to prove that $0$ is a limit point.

Answer (score 4):

$A$ is not open(with repsect to the usual topology) because it does not contain an open  interval around every point of it.

In general $A$ does not contain any interval.It has empty interior.

Also if $A$ was open then $A=A^o=\emptyset$ which is a contradiction.

> Now if you know the sequential characterization of a closed set in a metric space then taking $x_n \in A$ where $x_n= \frac{1}{n}$ then $x_n \to 0$ but $0 \notin A$.
>
> Thus we found a sequence in $A$ which has a limit that does not belong to $A$ thus it is not closed.

Also for another proof we will prove  that $A$ is not closed because its complement is not open.

> Assume that $A^c$ is open.We have that $0 \in A^c$ thus exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $0 \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \subseteq A^c.$
>
> Now we can use the Archimedeian property.
>
> So for this $\epsilon>0$  exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}< \epsilon$
>
> Thus $\frac{1}{n_0} \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \subseteq A^c$ and also $\frac{1}{n_0} \in A$ .
>
> This is a contradiction.So $A^c$ is not open.