# Let $Y_n=\{(x,1/n):x\in\mathbb{R},\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology. Is this set closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y_n=\{(x,\frac{1}{n}):x\in\mathbb{R},\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology. Is this set closed? I did a sketch and I can see that it is a union of lines. We know that the line is a closed set since it contains all its accumulation points, but we have an infinite union of closed sets [which are not connected] which is not necessarily closed.

Comment: Compare with the ideas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665896/prove-that-frac-1-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-cup-0-is-closed-in-mathbb). All limit points must also be contained then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not closed. The sequence $\left(\left(0,\frac1n\right)\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of your set which converges to $(0,0)$, which is outside your set.